# Best way to pass props for react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In React Js we can pass component props in two ways:

```
<Component
  prop1={value}
  prop2="value"
  prop3={this.othervalue}
/>
```

or

```
let props = {
  prop1: value,
  prop2: "value",
  prop3: this.othervalue
}

<Component {...props} />
```

What variant is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which you prefer? Neither is "right", though I think you're more likely to see the first variant, since it seems to be a bit clearer to pass the props explicitly. The spread params variant is generally used to avoid duplication - if you specify the props on a parent then want to pass them to the child, spelling them out explicitly on the child feels a bit laborious.

Comment: Ok, I think, I'll use first variant. I don't need duplication for this props, so far )